# Saving training data in json file in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, brain.js

I am training a data using a brain.js library in javascript.

```
const brain = require('brain.js')
const network = new brain.NeuralNetwork()
network.train([
    {input: {Workst: 0.0000, Worken: 0.6666, earlyMiss: 0, middleMiss: 0, lateMiss: 0}, output: {Fifth: 1} },
    {input: {Workst: 0.5555, Worken: 0.7777, earlyMiss: 0, middleMiss: 0, lateMiss: 0}, output: {Fifth: 1} },
    {input: {Workst: 0.0000, Worken: 0.4444, earlyMiss: 0, middleMiss: 0, lateMiss: 0}, output: {Fourth: 1} },
    {input: {Workst: 0.2222, Worken: 0.6666, earlyMiss: 0, middleMiss: 0, lateMiss: 0}, output: {Fifth: 1}},
    {input: {Workst: 0.4444, Worken: 0.9444, earlyMiss: 0, middleMiss: 0, lateMiss: 0}, output: {First: 1} },
    {input: {Workst: 0.3333, Worken: 0.9444, earlyMiss: 0, middleMiss: 0, lateMiss: 0}, output: {First: 1} },
    {input: {Workst: 0.0555, Worken: 0.5000, earlyMiss: 0, middleMiss: 0, lateMiss: 0}, output: {Fifth: 1} },
    {input: {Workst: 0.8333, Worken: 0.9444, earlyMiss: 0, middleMiss: 0, lateMiss: 0}, output: {Third: 1} },
    {input: {Workst: 0.7777, Worken: 0.8333, earlyMiss: 0, middleMiss: 0, lateMiss: 0}, output: {Second: 1} },
    {input: {Workst: 0.5555, Worken: 0.9444, earlyMiss: 0, middleMiss: 0, lateMiss: 0}, output: {Second: 1} },
    {input: {Workst: 0.6111, Worken: 0.9444, earlyMiss: 0, middleMiss: 0, lateMiss: 0}, output: {Third: 1} },
    {input: {Workst: 0.0005, Worken: 0.1666, earlyMiss: 0, middleMiss: 0, lateMiss: 0}, output: {Third: 1} },
    {input: {Workst: 0.2222, Worken: 0.6111, earlyMiss: 0, middleMiss: 0, lateMiss: 0}, output: {Fifth: 1} },
    {input: {Workst: 0.2222, Worken: 0.4444, earlyMiss: 0, middleMiss: 0, lateMiss: 0}, output: {Fifth: 1 } },
    {input: {Workst: 0.5555, Worken: 0.6666, earlyMiss: 0, middleMiss: 0, lateMiss: 0}, output: {Fourth: 1} },
])
const result = network.run({Workst: 0.5675, Worken: 0.90, earlyMiss: 0, middleMiss: 0, lateMiss: 0});

//const result = brain.likely({Age: 0.5, Experience: 1, BFP: 1, Calories: 0}, network);
console.log(result);
```

I will have to add new data points frequently and train data again, so I want to save training data somewhere. I want to save trianing data in a json file, and use something like

```
network.train("data.json");
```

everytime. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way that will work on small scale. Assuming you have your data in `data.json` you could do:

```js
const fs = require("fs")
//...
network.train(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("data.json", "utf-8")));
```

Further reading: https://nodejs.dev/learn/reading-files-with-nodejs/